# c# TCP socket how to validate incoming string and process it

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener

I have a `C# TPC Socket` with the following code:

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket.   
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // HERE WE NEED TO MAKE SURE THAT THE MESSAGE IS COMPLETE, IF NOT THEN READ MORE DATA

            if (bytesRead == ***something***)
            {
                //Do something HERE...
            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.  
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }

    }
```

The data that will be sent to the TCP Socket will be formed like this:

[image]

So the size can be different for every message. The first 10 bytes and the last 4 bytes are always fixed, but the payload is dynamic.

So I have to implement a way of validating the size of the message by intercepting the 4 bytes of the PAYLOAD SIZE position, that way is just matter of doing a sum of 2 + 4 + 4 + payload size + 4 so i can enter the if statement where I will do some other stuff there.

> Any advice or clue on the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving a string?

Comment: Im receiving a byte array

Comment: If it's not string data then you probably shouldn't be storing it as a string.

Comment: Yes I will remove that, you are right

Comment: @John how woudl you apend to byte array instead of doing the string append?

Comment: I'd use something like a `List<byte>`, but also don't forget that you aren't guaranteed to receive a single sent "message" in a single read. You might receive the start of a message, the end of a message, the end of a message and the start of another. That is to say, you will receive all of the data you sent, but it won't necessarily be in neatly partitioned messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    //put received bytes into queue for further processing
    //initiate BeginReceive
}
```

On another thread:

```
static void ProcessMessages()
{
    while(true)
    {
        //read messages from queue
        //check message frames
    }
}
```

You can check how it can be implemented in [simplsockets](https://github.com/haneytron/simplsockets/blob/master/SimplSockets/SimplSocketClient.cs), method `ProcessReceivedMessage`.